# Set header for all except one location

Tags: nginx, http-headers

I'd like to set a header on all page request except for one. I've tried the following:

```
location ~ ^\/(?!allow-iframes) { 
  add_header 'X-Frame-Options' 'DENY';
}
```

This has some unexpected behavior. It causes a 301 redirect on all pages except `/allow-iframes`.

I came across [this](https://fedingo.com/how-to-add-conditional-headers-in-nginx/) but I can't use `map` since it only works inside `http` and not inside the `server` context.